# JSLink Client-side rendering

Tags: 2013, javascript, client-object-model, column, jslink

I need to render some fields client-side,
I followed this guide: [Client-side rendering](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-code-0a786cdd) but this code is not working:

```
(function () { 

    // Create object that have the context information about the field that we want to change it's output render  
    var priorityFiledContext = {}; 
    priorityFiledContext.Templates = {}; 
    priorityFiledContext.Templates.Fields = { 
        // Apply the new rendering for Priority field on List View 
        "Title": { "View": priorityFiledTemplate } 
    }; 

    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(priorityFiledContext); 

})(); 

// This function provides the rendering logic for list view 
function priorityFiledTemplate(ctx) { 
   alert("in");
   return "New Title";
}
```

I binded the script in the JSLink section of the webpart. (the script is in the Layout filder)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this should work

```
RegisterModuleInit('/<yourSiteName>/SiteAssets/<yourJSfilename>.js', updateTitle);
updateTitle();

function updateTitle() {
    var priorityFiledContext  = {};
    priorityFiledContext.Templates = {};    
    priorityFiledContext.Templates.Fields = {
        "Title": {
            "View": priorityFiledTemplate
        }
    };

    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(priorityFiledContext);
}

function priorityFiledTemplate(ctx) {
    return "New Title";
}
```

Also i suggest uploading the .js file in your Site Assets Library and linking it to the Webpart (edit > misc > JSLink) with:

```
~site/SiteAssets/<yourJSfilename>.js
```

*remember to Change  and* 
Also I suggest to use JSBin to check your future code for Syntax Errors
and also use the browser console (press F12) to debug. Make sure you select script in the console and refresh after you upload your script, to see where any Problems were encountered (if any).

Comment: No luck, the function priorityFiledTemplate is not called

Comment: Hmm, that's strange. Could you provide any more Information? What does the console say exactly when you refresh the page?

Comment: No exception, the main function (updateTitle in your example) is executed but the other function is not. In the page I have other list views does it matter?

Comment: Edited the script above (found a minor Syntax error) should work now, hopefully. Try to copy it again.

Comment: Not working yet. Do I need to import some SP libraries?

Comment: No you don't have to. Did you Change the <> in the provided code to meet your requirements? (there are 3)
Also note that the title will be changed to "New Title" for all the list items items only in the current site where you inserted the web-part(List) and linked it to the script. So on any other site the title will reamain unchanged.

Comment: The problem was on the Title field, I think is not possible to change it :/

Comment: Have you tried another field? Maybe one of your custom ones? Note that columns with space are separeted by : _x0020_
eg: 
    priorityFiledContext.Templates.Fields = {
        "Test_x0020_Field" : {
            "View": priorityFiledTemplate
        }
    };

Comment: Yes, with my custom fields is working fine, thank you for the support :)

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
(function () {
    // Intialize the variables for overrides objects
    (window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"><\/script>'));
    var overrideCtx = {};
    overrideCtx.Templates = {};
    overrideCtx.Templates.Fields = {
        'Color': 
        {
        'NewForm': ingredientsNewAndEdit
        }
    };
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideCtx);
})(); 


function ingredientsNewAndEdit(Ctx) {       
    alert("Test");      
    var formCtx =SPClientTemplates.Utility.GetFormContextForCurrentField(ctx);      
    var FieldHtml = "<div><input type='Text' Id='txtColor' FieldInternalName='Color'FieldType='SPFieldText'/></div>";       
    return FieldHtml;
}
```

this Code is perfectly render the control .

Just check it out your path of the js link . your webpart is at sitecollection level or web level ? if sitecollection level than

> Path : ~Sitecollection/(Your Jslink  file path) (Sitecollection)
>
> Path : ~Site/(your jslink file path)(Web level)